# calling Beginwaitcursor function from worker thread in MFC

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc

Can someone help me in understanding the worker threads in VC++(MFC)?
Following is my workerthread function

```
UINT ThreadFunc(LPVOID pParam)
{
// some initialization... etc..

AfxGetApp()->BeginWaitCursor();

...
..
/// some operations

AfxGetApp()->End WaitCursor();

}
```

Is it okay to call WaitCursor() functions from a worker thread?

Comment: It is "okay", but it won't have the intended effect. The UI thread will just change them right back. A better solution is to display a control on the window/dialog itself that indicates something is happening in the background.

Comment: In MFC you can use `CWaitCursor x;` and it is done when `x` goes out of scope. However it still doesn't do anything here, for reasons explained earlier.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation available for [`BeginWaitCursor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dh4h02k4.aspx) and [`EndWaitCursor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31kzkkbz.aspx) make no mention of issues related to threading.

The one thing that is mentioned,

> The actions of BeginWaitCursor are not always effective outside of a single message handler as other actions, such as OnSetCursor handling, could change the cursor.

Other threads can change the cursor as well while your worker thread is working.

Also you need to consider the actions of the `CWnd` message handler `OnSetCursor()` which handles the `WM_SETCURSOR` message if the `ON_WM_SETCURSOR()` macro is added to the message map for a `CWnd` derived class. See [Prevent MFC application to change cursor back to default icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36170858/prevent-mfc-application-to-change-cursor-back-to-default-icon)