# Prevent MFC application to change cursor back to default icon

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, mfc

I have written an application which changes the cursor depending on its position within the window client area. However I have noticed that when I click on the left mouse button the cursor changes back to default arrow icon.

I have overridden the `afx_msg void CWnd::OnLButtonDown()` and do not call any of the base class function in it (it's completely empty).

Any idea what might cause `CDialogEx` to change the cursor back? What handles the the left click message?

Comment: You have not shown much code, it's not clear what you are doing or what you are after. Start by overloading `OnSetCursor()`

Comment: I am more or less trying to write my own window manger similar to MDI MFC application, so I draw my own windows inside dialog with borders and trying to mimic the cursor standard cursor behaviour. However it seams that just setting the irght kind of cursor is not enough. You gave me a good direction also I beliove that hot-spot regions testing is also something I need to think about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, you need to override `OnSetCursor()`, and there, if the mouse is in a place where you want a specific cursor, you call `SetCursor()` and return `TRUE` so that `DefWindowProc` doesn't reset it back to the default arrow.